# Requests Different Data Between Python 2 vs Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am having an issue converting some simple get request code from Python 2 to 3. Running the same code with same version of requests (2.25.1) I get different response headers as well as content.  Using Py2, I get content/text properly.  However the with same code in Py3 I get garbled content/text. Is there a difference in how Py3 handles a get request??

```
response = requests.get(url)
print (response.headers)
print (response.text)
```

Header response, Py2 vs 3. Note some proprietary data was removed from the Py2 header. Data does not appear in Py3 header.

```
{'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Connection': 'close', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Jan 2021 16:36:11 GMT', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/6.0', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' }

{'Connection': 'close', 'Date': 'Tue, 26 Jan 2021 16:36:16 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/6.0'}
```

Example py3 content.

```
a
▼     ♦
408
ܙAo�8►���¶V.��BI���B�.��������V��♀��N��↔Z���N)��n��]♫U2L�~�↓�ӑ��♀►aX��%p�2�ܓ��ܓ���ѳ;�(�`5���k,HFS9¶◄�♣���n��
```

I have tried to .encode('utf-8') the response.text but I get a string like
`a\r\n\x1f\xef\xbf\xbd\x08\x00\x00\`
Why is there a difference between the same request in different versions of python?

Comment: `'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'`...? Nothing about `gzip` in the header for Python 3?

Comment: Both Py2 and 3 have the same request header.  I have not added any custom headers.  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*' is listed. I did try to gzip decompress the content thinking it might be compressed. But errored saying it was not.

Comment: Then check the server side. In my experience, I had to do something to deal with encoding when I use Python2. If your client sides are the same and only the Py2 client correctly works, your server side could do something extra for Python2 client which is not mecessary to Py3 client.

Comment: I don't own the server so I am unable to investigate that.  The request URL works fine in Py2 and in the Browser.  So I am unsure why Py3 is behaving differently.

Answer (score 0):

How about to try:

```
print(response.encoding)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: the .encoding shows as utf-8.  printing content shows that same as if I drop encoding on the response.text.  Just a string of chars a\r\n\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\  I believe this is in bytes though.  I tried a decode with utf-8 and states decode a byte.  No idea why this is so different in Py3 compared to Py2.